# À quoi s'applique la négation « non » ?

Tags: sens, négation, antécédent

Voici une discussion :

« Je pensais que Charlemagne s'était couronné empereur lui-même.

—  D'après cet article, non.»

Quel sens doit-on donner au « non » ?

1. Non, il ne s'est pas couronné empereur lui-même.
2. Non, tu ne pensais pas qu'il s'était couronné empereur lui-même.

En d'autres termes est-ce que le « non » nie la subordonnée « Charlemagne s'est couronné empereur lui-même » ou bien la phrase « Je pensais que...» ?

Je penche pour la solution 1 mais une amie me soutient que c'est l'autre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sans contexte, le sens le plus évident est bien sûr la proposition 1.

En coupant les cheveux en 4, on pourrait imaginer une situation où l'interlocuteur aurait écrit un article disant que Charlemagne ne s'était pas couronné lui-même, ce qui rendrait la proposition 2 plausible, mais c'est franchement tarabiscoté.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse.

Comment: @Tom-Tom, contrairement à l'anglais , il faut utiliser `de` et non `pour` avec `merci` ;)

Comment: @Flying_whale. Je ferai attention à m'en souvenir.